# How long do ice arrows freeze for?

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

How long, in seconds, does it take for an enemy to thaw after being hit by an ice arrow? Is it a random amount of time or a fixed amount? I know that Darknuts break free almost immediately, but how long does it take for other enemies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always a fixed amount, but it depends on the enemy (actually, I think Darknuts and ReDeads are the only normal enemies in the game that break free instantly. You can use the Skull Hammer jump attack to destroy them before they unfreeze, fun fact of the day). I don't know exactly how long it takes for a normal enemy, but come on... just use your head, or a stopwatch if you're in for precision.